# How to create for loop that shows data for all users in drop down menu?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, psql

I am making a `CRUD` application in `Flask`. I successful make `create` data with drop down menu, but I can not make `update` with drop down menu.
Drop down menu only shows data for first row in application. After I choose new value from drop down menu for the first item and send, page refreshes and new row comes to the first place and for other rows the drop down menu shows nothing.

[Web site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpwju.png)

I don`t know where is problem.

## html

```
 {% for trudnoca in trudnoce %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{trudnoca.id_korisnice}}" name="oldid_korisnice">

       <select name="newid_korisnice" method="POST" action="updateTrudnoca">
    {% for korisnica2 in korisnice2 %}
        <option value="{{korisnica2.OIB}}" SELECTED>{{korisnica2.ime}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}</select>
```

## main

```
@app.route("/modifyTrudnoca", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def modifyTrudnoca():
    korisnice=sql("SELECT * FROM korisnica;")
    korisnice2=sql("SELECT * FROM korisnica;")
    trudnoce=None

    if request.form:
        try:
             trudnoca = Trudnoca(id_trudnoce=request.form.get("id_trudnoce"),
                            id_korisnice=request.form.get("id_korisnice"),
                            pocetak=request.form.get("pocetak"),
                            kraj=request.form.get("kraj"),
                            opis=request.form.get("opis"))
             db.session.add(trudnoca)
             db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
             print("Oops, pogreška se dogodila, pokušajte ponovno")
             print(e)
    trudnoce = Trudnoca.query.all()
    return render_template("updateTrudnoca.html",korisnice2=korisnice2,trudnoce=trudnoce,korisnice=korisnice)
```

Comment: Where are you sending a `post` request back to `modifyTrudnoca()`? Right now, you're only sending a `get` request.

Comment: I changed some things and now it updates but only shows drop down menu for the first row. I updated posted photo and code.